# How can I read and write from a grpc stream simultaneously

Tags: c++, rpc, grpc

I am now implementing the Raft algorithm, and I want to use gRPC stream to do this. My main idea is to create 3 streams for each node to every other peers, one stream will transmit one type of RPCs, there are `AppendEntries`, `RequestVote` and `InstallSnapshot`. I write some code with limited help from [route_guide](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/route_guide/route_guide_client.cc), because in its bidirectional stream demo `RouteChat`, the client send all its data before it starts to read.

Firstly, I want to write to a stream at any time, so I write the following codes

```
void RaftMessagesStreamClientSync::AsyncRequestVote(const RequestVoteRequest& request){
    std::string peer_name = this->peer_name;
    debug("GRPC: Send RequestVoteRequest from %s to %s\n", request.name().c_str(), peer_name.c_str());
    request_vote_stream->Write(request);
}
```

Meanwhile, I want a thread keep reading from a stream, like the following codes, which is called immediately after `RaftMessagesStreamClientSync` is constructed.

```
void RaftMessagesStreamClientSync::handle_response(){
    // strongThis is a must 
    auto strongThis = shared_from_this();
    t1 = new std::thread([strongThis](){
        RequestVoteResponse response;
        while (strongThis->request_vote_stream->Read(&response)) {
            debug("GRPC: Recv RequestVoteResponse from %s, me %s\n", response.name().c_str(), strongThis->raft_node->name.c_str());
            ...
        }
    });
    ...
```

In order to initialize 3 streams, I have to write the constructor like this, I use 3 `ClientContext` here because the [document says one ClientContext for one RPC](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_client_context.html#details)

```
struct RaftMessagesStreamClientSync : std::enable_shared_from_this<RaftMessagesStreamClientSync>{
    typedef grpc::ClientReaderWriter<RequestVoteRequest, RequestVoteResponse> CR;
    typedef grpc::ClientReaderWriter<AppendEntriesRequest, AppendEntriesResponse> CA;
    typedef grpc::ClientReaderWriter<InstallSnapshotRequest, InstallSnapshotResponse> CI;

    std::unique_ptr<CR> request_vote_stream;
    std::unique_ptr<CA> append_entries_stream;
    std::unique_ptr<CI> install_snapshot_stream;
    ClientContext context_r;
    ClientContext context_a;
    ClientContext context_i;
    std::thread * t1 = nullptr;
    std::thread * t2 = nullptr;
    std::thread * t3 = nullptr;
    ...
}
RaftMessagesStreamClientSync::RaftMessagesStreamClientSync(const char * addr, struct RaftNode * _raft_node) : raft_node(_raft_node), peer_name(addr) {
    std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel = grpc::CreateChannel(addr, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
    stub = raft_messages::RaftStreamMessages::NewStub(channel);
    // 1
    request_vote_stream = stub->RequestVote(&context_r);
    // 2
    append_entries_stream = stub->AppendEntries(&context_a);
    // 3
    install_snapshot_stream = stub->InstallSnapshot(&context_i);    
}
~RaftMessagesStreamClientSync() {
    raft_node = nullptr;
    t1->join();
    t2->join();
    t3->join();
    delete t1;
    delete t2;
    delete t3;
}
```

Then I implement the server side

```
Status RaftMessagesStreamServiceImpl::RequestVote(ServerContext* context, ::grpc::ServerReaderWriter< ::raft_messages::RequestVoteResponse, RequestVoteRequest>* stream){
    RequestVoteResponse response;
    RequestVoteRequest request;
    while (stream->Read(&request)) {
        ...
    }

    return Status::OK;
}
```

Then 2 problems happen:

1. When I test with 3 nodes, which actually creates 2 `RaftMessagesStreamServiceImpl` for each node, the statement from 1 to 3 cost a long time to execute.
2. There is no RPC received from server side.
   There are similar problems when using [Bidi Aysnc Server](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/DIeehyvJIs0), However I can't figure out how this post can help me.

**UPDATE**

After some debugging, I found `request_vote_stream->Write(request)` returns 0, which, according to the [document, means the stream is closed](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_client_reader_writer.html#ae30b0e18622f4132b1c7654e24605d53). However why is it closed?

Comment: Your code is C++. Please do not add C language tag if you don't use C language at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, I found that the two problem are all due to one problem that I create a client before I create a server.

Because I originally uses unary RPC calls, so a previous call from client only causes a gRPC error code 14. The program continues because every call sent after the server is created can be handled correctly.

However, when it comes to streaming calls, `stub->RequestVote(&context_r)` will end up calling a blocking function `ClientReaderWriter::ClientReaderWriter`, which will try to connect to the server, which is not created now.

```
/// Block to create a stream and write the initial metadata and \a request
/// out. Note that \a context will be used to fill in custom initial metadata
/// used to send to the server when starting the call.
ClientReaderWriter(::grpc::ChannelInterface* channel,
                 const ::grpc::internal::RpcMethod& method,
                 ClientContext* context)
  : context_(context),
    cq_(grpc_completion_queue_attributes{
        GRPC_CQ_CURRENT_VERSION, GRPC_CQ_PLUCK,
        GRPC_CQ_DEFAULT_POLLING}),  // Pluckable cq
    call_(channel->CreateCall(method, context, &cq_)) {
if (!context_->initial_metadata_corked_) {
  ::grpc::internal::CallOpSet<::grpc::internal::CallOpSendInitialMetadata>
      ops;
  ops.SendInitialMetadata(context->send_initial_metadata_,
                          context->initial_metadata_flags());
  call_.PerformOps(&ops);
  cq_.Pluck(&ops);
}
}
```

As a consequence, the connection has not yet been established.